# distributed data reader across multiple machines

Tags: tensorflow

is there any distributed data reader for TensorFlow? 
if not, what is the suggested way for handling big datasets over multiple machines?

The distributed inception example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) pre-segments the data over multiple machines and then each workers grabs its subset of data from available subsets. Is this the only supported method?

Also it seems that some of the data readers described in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) are thread safe but I couldn't find any distributed solution.

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently have a general solution for distributed data reading in TensorFlow, and it's a bit of a hard problem since there are many different possible requirements around latency, size, and sharding. I'd be very interested in any proposals or patches though!